# Should I make my primary user an Administrator or not?

Tags: macos, security, accounts

For a long time, I have had two accounts on my Mac : an administrator account that I normally don't use, and a "normal user" that I use for day-to-day work. I did this because it should be more secure to work in an account with fewer privileges.

The drawback is that I get more security popups. And I believe Apple's standard practice is still to give you administrator rights when you do a standard install.

I will be installing a clean system soon, so my question is: should I continue using two accounts or just have one account for everything? Is having two accounts more secure *in practice*? or am I just annoying myself for no real reason?

Comment: I concur with the recommendation to just use an administrator account, with one amendment: I always create a 2nd administrator account (just called 'admin' or some such) which I use in case my primary administrator account gets hosed. I have only needed this very, very rarely, but it's a nice safety net to have "just in case."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's differentiate a user being one **individual** from a user being a single **UNIX user account**.

As for the purpose of limiting privileges to the computer account and not for the individual operating it, creating two separate user accounts in Mac OS X is overkill and if you ask me rather impractical. Even an administrator account lacks the privileges to modify anything system critical without authenticating as the root user, which requires manually re-entering your password.

The only significant extra privilege an administrator account has is the ability to switch to the root (privileged) account. If you are familiar with the `sudo` command in the shell, this is very much the same thing.

You would create a regular user account as opposed to an administrator account if you want to limit privileges of the individual operating the computer, for example with kids or employees.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, without sudo-ing (by entering password), an administrator user has pretty much the same limits as a normal user? In that case there is no reason for me to work on a normal account and I will install my new system using only an admin account.

Comment: Basically, an administrator account is a regular account with sudo access.

Comment: @Gerry, it's close but not exactly the same—I gave my normal user sudo privileges, and I still need to authenticate with my admin user for unlocking preference panes and such.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54135/149366) reads like an opinion rather than a factual answer. But of course finding factual answers with Apple products is often difficult due to sparse documentation, and ever-changing even when the documentation exists. Granted, computer security is always in flux, but while we all appreciate Apple's efforts, we may also wish that Apple could be a bit more clear and forthcoming. Even the most [experienced users struggle](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/07/21/owners-and-users-primary-and-secondary-systems-on-m1-macs/) to comprehend exactly **what** Apple's security measures are.

That said, the currently accepted answer is [*out-of-step*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+step) with Apple's guidance and documentation as published in the macOS User Guide since at least macOS Mojave (10.14).

Under the topic of [Set up your Mac to be secure](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/flvlt003/13.0/mac/13.0) in the section labeled "Limit the number of administrative users", the following statement appears as a direct answer to the OP's question:

> ... an administrator should create a standard user account to use when administrator privileges are not needed.

This advice is given unequivocally, and justified with the statement that:

> If the security of a standard user is compromised, the potential harm is far more limited than if the user has administrator privileges